# Test a method that use a spring service

Tags: java, spring, junit, junit4

I have a problem testing a method in Java (I use jUnit 4) and this method to test make a call to a repository and should throw an exception if something is wrong, the method looks like:

```
//Method located in a Spring service and use a repository to make the query
public void updateCustomer(CustomerEntity customer) throws CustomException {
        try {
            getDataDao().update(customer);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new CustomException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

The question is, How can I make for the test case enter the catch block and throw the exception? I am setting the customer to null but don't work.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mock that DAO call and throw and exception from there.

You will get more idea about @Mock, @InjectMock and [@Mockito](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-exceptions) framework [here](https://www.journaldev.com/21887/mockito-injectmocks-mocks-dependency-injection).

```
  Mockito.when(getDataDao().update(any()))
      .thenThrow(Exception.class);
```

Comment: @Ed great..!! 

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the **mockito** framework.If you are an absolute beginner for this framework ,then I recommend you to refer the following tutorials.
[Mockito - Exception Handling](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mockito/mockito_exception_handling.htm)